# Satisfying a framework's dependencies while within another project

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am working on an iOS framework. My development environment is an iOS application project with the framework project within it, the framework's product is then added to the "Embedded binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" sections of the application.

The previous setup works fine, but this particular framework I'm working on requires one other framework to function. I have installed this framework via Carthage and added it to the base application's project ("Embedded binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries") and then also the framework's project "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

However when I run the application I get the following two errors (`FrameworkOne` is the framework I'm working on in a project, `FrameworkTwo` is the dependency):

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found:
  [symbol here]

Referenced from:
  [path to iOS sim]/FrameworkOne.framework/FrameworkOne

Expected in:
  [path to application]/Frameworks/FrameworkTwo.framework/FrameworkTwo
```

...and...

```
dyld: Symbol not found:
  [symbol here]

...the same paths as above...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple and frustrating in hindsight: the version of the framework used within my application project and my framework project didn't match.

If you're having similar issues check that your application and framework are using the same version!